# Single Identity for Desktop and Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, identity

I'm building a system has both a WPF desktop application as well as an Asp.net MVC application.

I need a common user identity component so that user can log on to either one with the same credentials.

Is ASP.NET Identity appropriate for this task?

Has anyone used ASP.NET Identity with a WPF application?

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: windows integrated authentication?

Comment: @LachlanB provides the easiest alternative. The most flexible alternative is probably this one - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4656.wpf-application-with-live-id-facebook-google-yahoo-open-id.aspx which details implementation WPF but moving this across to MVC is fairly painless.

Comment: tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like OpenID Connect built on top of oAuth 2.0 would be applicable?

Users can manage their identities with an Identity Provider.
Your Web and Desktop applications become Relying Parties and they will be given an ID Token and possibly an Access Token when the user is authenticated with the Identity Provider.

The Identity Provider could be extended to federate onto other Identity Providers such as ADFS, Google, Facebook...